# How to remove only one validation attribute before checking ModelState.IsValid on server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, required

I have below model class. that is shared by multiple views.

Now, For the view1.cshtml both validation attribute(i.e `RegularExpression`,`Required`) working fine so I don't need to do anything for that.

Problem is when I submit my second view2.cshtml I want to remove `Required` validation attribute but not `RegularExpression`.

Model class has below property

```
[RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z]{5}\d{4}[A-Za-z]{1}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The PAN no field is required")]
public string pan { get; set; }
```

I tried below code to remove Required validation but it also remove RegularExpression validation.

```
ModelState.Remove("pan");
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{

}
```

Comment: I believe **CustomAttribute** could help you sort your problem out.

Comment: @Skrface Is there any reference for CustomeAttribute for this situation.

Comment: doesnt really address what youre asking directly but its thought as best practice to have a separate vm for each view. this helps prevent stuff like overposting/underposting attacks and makes the situation youre trying to address into a trivial problem. What's more clear? two viewmodels or one viewmodel that has a custom written data attribute to conditionally remove validation on one of the vm properties

Comment: Actually my VM is shared by multiple views. for this single property validation I have to create multiple copie's of the same VM for each view. this is the only reason to use many view to single model

Comment: @MannanBahelim it's still a good idea to separate them. If all of the views sharing this vm use ALL of the properties in the vm, then sure, go ahead and keep them all using the same vm (although I'm guessing some of your views use subsets of properties from this vm) until one needs to be different. This sounds like the first time one needs to be different and warrants a separate view model being created.

Comment: @MannanBahelim you can also use **$("#pan").rules("remove", "required");** using jQuery

Comment: @KiranJoshi I guess it is ok for client side validation.what about server side

Comment: @GregH thanks ,let me try with separate vm.

Comment: You can check and add error dynamically using AddModelError in the controller-action and remove the validation from the attribute.

Comment: @JeevaJsb please read my question carefully.I don't want to add error in my model. just want to remove only one Required attribute not regularexpression

Comment: I meant the same.. Remove required attribute. In controller action, based on your condition add model state error before you validate ModalState.IsValid. So that will satisfy your condition..

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
 ModelState["pan"].Errors.Clear();
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the errors from field. If i add this statement how could I check entered value has passed the regular expression